# Add RelativeLayout with buttons below RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I need to add a RelativeLayout below my RecyclerView and was able to do so, except that the button under TOTAL(R.id.total_amount_tv) does not show:

[image]

I can easily scroll through the items and it doesn't affect my RelativeLayout. I just need the button to be visible.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_tv"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
            android:text="@string/order_btn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to divide the screen in to two Parts one for showing the Recyclerview and other for RelativeLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/order_recycler"
        android:layout_weight = "8.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ShoppingCartActivity" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight = "1.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/total_tv"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Total Right"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

         <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/total_amount_tv"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="onClickSendOrder"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
     </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will produce the following results

[image: Picture]

Comment: It works. But please add `android:layout_height="0dp"` in RecyclerView also.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This is the likely culprit. Both TextViews are aligned at the bottom of their parent RelativeLayout. This doesn't leave room for the Button.

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/downline_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lin_result"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#f8ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#999898" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_total_rupees"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="100" 
         android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
       </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```